# How to find the version of middleware used in Express Framework

Tags: express

Is there a way to find the version of middleware(eg.sequelize) used in Express Framework. We can find in the package.json, rather than that is there any way to find the version.

Comment: Run `npm ls sequelize` in the project directory.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks its working.